# Angular Error Invalid ICU message. Missing

Tags: html, angular, eof

I develop an angular application. If I build my application with the command ng build --prod, I get the following error

```
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
[ERROR ->]"):
```

I dont know what this error means and where I have to search to fix it.
My code is the following in the app.html

```
<div class="">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">

  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

    <!-- Grid row -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">

        <!-- Content -->
        <img id="logo" style="max-width:200px;  margin: 0 auto" src="../assets/img/logo.png"/>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Kategorie</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
              Shopping</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'Hotels_Flüge',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
               Hotels & Flüge</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'DSL_Handy',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
              DSL & Handy</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'Versicherungen',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
              Versicherungen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'Kredite_Konto',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
              Kredite & Konto</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]={categorie:'Gas_Strom',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}>
              Gas & Strom</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Unternehmen</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/impressum">Impressum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/datenschutz">Datenschutz</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="https://www.facebook.com/">Instagram</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

  </div>
  <!-- Footer Links -->

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="test"> tzu</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
```

Can someone tell me, what this error means and how to fix it ? I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your queryParams in double quotes:

```
[queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}"
```